# CodeIgniter URI Routing for a complex URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Problem is:

**Controller:** products
**Method:** product_details(category_name, product_name)

**Current URL is:** http://www.domain.com/products/product_details/category-name/product-name

But i don't want the above url, I want to enter below URL and its remapped on the above mention method

**URL TO MAPPED:** http://www.domain.com/product/category-name/product-name

How to do it using routes.php in codeigniter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$route['products/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'products/product_details/$1/$2';
```

If your products controller has any other methods you will need to specify routes for them above this, as this is essentially a catch all route for your products controller.